# "настройка" идентификатора в .net

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Имею лист объектов. Как произвести удаление объекта по ID, в роли которого будет выступать поле имя? то бишь как выбрать само поле имя в качестве идентификатора, которое потом на ввод будем спрашивать?

(дальнейшие-то действия ясны - запрашиваем и вводим имя,по возможности удаляем объект с указанным набором символов)

**Обновление**

Список объектов вида

```
public Racer(string NAME, string COUNTRY, string TEAM, string AGE)
{
    name = NAME;
    country = COUNTRY;
    team = TEAM;
    age = AGE;
}
...
List<Racer> racers;
```

Хочу сделать так, чтобы я могла удалять гонщика по введенному имени.

Comment: Я думаю, что не все здесь такие грамотные, как вы, и могут не знать, что вы имеете в виду, говоря про лист. Не могли бы вы показать код, который демонстрирует проблему?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

Вот небольшой пример со списком гонщиков. Допустим на форме есть textBox1 для ввода имени гонщика и button1 на который мы нажимаем, когда ввели имя гонщика, которого необходимо удалить

```
class Racer 
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Country {get;set;}
    public string Team {get;set;}
    public string Age {get;set;}
}

List<Student> racers = new List();

//заполнияем список

//Пример добавления меня
racers.Add(
    new Racer(){Name = "Умед", Country = "Россия", Team = "SO", Age = "22"}
);

//событие клика по кнопке
void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string name = textBox1.Text;

    racers.RemoveAll(racer => racer.Name == name); 
}
```

Comment: как этот способ применить к случаю, когда мы вводим в поле на форме имя, по которому будем удалять?

Comment: то бишь произвести сравнение того, что ввели в поле с именами, которые имеются, чтобы затем удалить объект

Comment: допустим на форме у Вас есть textBox1 в которое вводится имя гонщика и кнопка button1, делаете событие на нажатие button1 и в него такой код
`lists.RemoveAll(student => student.Name == textBox1.Text);`

Comment: @daryasaturday выше обновил пост с примером под Ваш класс

Comment: прелесть, поняла! Спасибо!